# AWS RDS Postgres/Iam Authentication/ and Row Level Security - All In One. Is this possible?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-rds

I have an app that will have many users at various levels of privileges on what they can "See/Select".

The users form a hierarchy. Level1--> Level2--Level3 etc.  Level1 users may have many level2 users, similarly Level2 users may have many level3 users . Each user can see anything that belongs to them or anyone directly below them. For example: A level 2 user can see all level 3 users information that rolls up to her but cannot see , any level 3 users that rolls up to other level 2 users.... You get the idea.

All userids are unique.

I am thinking of implementing Row Level Security with policies to restrict based on the userid. This is working at the database level by implementing Row level security and policies.

However, I would like to know how this can be achieved with IAM roles and IAM based authentication?

I read the documentation. It states, that while I can create a IAM roles and assign them privileges at the db level, and individual users can be assigned to these IAM roles to access the database using authtokens, it does not state how I can track each of the users at the database level to ensure that they can only see their data?

Any insights appreciated.

S

Comment: I suggest looking through this info on how RDS IAM authentication works: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/ You are just mapping an IAM role to a database user, so if you do that once for each of your existing database users it should work like you want.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB.I want to know if I could avoid adding each user to this role. This seems tedious. My application may have 1000s of users, and more signing up daily. The plan is to have them self-register (Cognito AWS) and the cognito pools will map to the IAM authenticated roles and the permissions should be provided in that fashion. So my first step was to create db user as per the AWS documentation and then an IAM role for that user... So far it was successful. However, I am unable to login from a EC2 instance using "Authtoken" .... It's not working.

Comment: You would have to have a separate DB account for each user if you wanted row level security. Why are you allowing users to login via Cognito and then run direct SQL queries against your database anyway? Are you providing some sort of SQL database service?

Comment: There will be 10s of 1000s of users and I don't want to create a userid in the database. So I would like to maintain the users and credentials in AWS Cognito and give them a role based access to the database. Is this possible? Along the same lines, the users should be able to see *ONLY* their data (i.e. RLS). So I need a way to use a global session variable with the userid to pass to the RLS policy to restrict data access. I am not entirely sure all this is possible. I searched so much but could not find an answer. I thought I should check here and see what experts have to say.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be possible. Can you explain why you are giving 10s of 1000s of users direct access to query your database? It seems like you are trying to solve this security problem in the wrong application layer.

Answer (score 2):

If you google "SaaS Multi-tenant Storage Isolation" You'll find a number of resources on this topic. The short answer is that you can achieve what you are trying to do (pool isolation enforced by IAM policies) with DynamoDB. But with RDS you have to rely on database users and PostgeSQL RLS features.

If you look at the IAM documentation for DyanmoDB and RDS condition keys, you'll see that with DynamoDB you can filter actions based on things like "dynamodb:LeadingKeys" or "dynamodb:Attributes". Where as RDS you do not have filters that get as granular as individual indicies or attributes.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html#amazonrds-policy-keys
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazondynamodb.html#amazondynamodb-policy-keys

Here's some addtional material on the topic worth looking at:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuDZq-EspNA (includes examples at ~35mins)
- https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Multi_Tenant_SaaS_Storage_Strategies.pdf
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/multi-tenant-data-isolation-with-postgresql-row-level-security/